# Как понять термин «пигеоцефальный»?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, выбор-слов

Нашла такое слово — «пигеоцефальный». А значения отыскать не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста. Это вроде бы что-то связанное с медициной, так что очень прошу врачей откликнуться).

Comment: Это случайно не из этого предложения: ***гемисферная пигеоцефальная дисфункциональная интерференция?***

Comment: Серж, да! Отсюда:). Причём только одно слово из этого выражения я для полноты картины истолковать не могу.

Comment: Пигео — кроме, цефал — мозг. Вроде просто :)

Comment: Мне кажется, там ошибка. Мне удалось найти похожий термин. Плагиоцефалия (лат. plagiocephalia от др.-греч. πλάγιος «косой» и κεφαλή «голова») — описательный термин, означающий асимметрию человеческого черепа либо его искривлённую косую форму независимо от причин возникновения

Comment: Или же, может быть, намерено искажено слово, так сказать, игра слов.

Comment: Danatela, мне не просто). Спасибо!

Comment: В любом случае, я написал им, может, откликнутся. Если напишут, я напишу здесь.

Comment: @Danatela - а откуда такой перевод? **pigeo** - это латинский глагол, ( https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pigeo ) при чем тут "кроме"?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Гемисферная пигеоцефальная дисфункциональная интерференция"*** - это псевдодонаучная абракадабра, своего рода макаронизм, имитация, дразнилка. Вы бы эту абракадабру в вопрос вынесли, а то я всерьез принял.

***Пигеоцефальный*** в дословном переводе значит *"имеющий голубиный мозг"* (pigeon - голубь), но термин *"голубиные мозги"* - это совершенно не научный термин, бытовая характеристика недалекого человека.

Все вместе - некий "научный" синоним хорошо известному *"фимозу головного мозга"*.

> Пигео — кроме, цефал — мозг. Вроде просто

Кстати, тоже вариант. Не "кроме", конечно, а освобождаться (от греха), каяться. 
Но, правда, случай нехарактерный для медицинской латыни.

> Danatela, мне не просто)

Что так? Вы всерьез эту фразу восприняли? Да вы на источник посмотрите, он же совершенно не медицинский.

> "Гемисферная пигеоцефальная дисфункциональная интерференция" как
>   говаривала в возрасте двенадцати лет mademoiselle моя племянница.

https://trolleybust.com/?ftent=616956695038402

> Не умом, ибо у названных и не названных выше дамов несомненно
>   наличествует гемисферная пигеоцефальная дисфункциональная
>   интерференция (шуточка, шедшая на ура, когда моей племяннице и ее
>   одноклассникам было одиннадцать лет, но едва ли доступная интеллекту
>   божен), а нутром, кожей, рожей.

http://www.4pera.ru/news/kolumnistika/evgenika_ot_kutyur/
(Одного автора, судя по всему.)

Оно? Или где-то ещё "позаимствовали"?

Comment: Мимоходов, да, ещё где-то). Вообще насчёт того, что это «дразнилка», как Вы заметили, любому понятно... Но я полагала, что эта абракадабра составлена из нагромождения существующих, а не придуманных терминов, и вследствие этого восприняла всерьёз.)

Comment: @Мимоходов Извините, но Ваша первая ссылка "неоткрывабельная". А хотелось бы посмотреть.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  У меня все ссылки рабочие.  https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZLdwWc7CEuHX6QTawJTADQ